# Deriving formula to find time it takes for two discs to reach same angular velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics, rotation

Assuming that the coefficient of friction between the two discs, $\mu$, is independent of speed, and that disc 1 with a radius R1 (the bottom disc) is initially moving with angular velocity $\omega$ and disc 2, with a radius of R2, is stationary. Then disc 2, the top disc, falls onto disc 2. Derive the formula it takes for the two to rotate at the same angular velocity. Also discs 1 and discs 2 have the same mass, $M$.

Is my logic correct here that the friction $\mu Mg$ will provide a torque, all along the radius of the top disc, and so if I sum all of these torques (integrate), I should be able to find the change in angular momentum, $dJ/dT$, and hence derive a formula for the angular velocity as a function of time?

And similarly can I can do this for the bottom disc and equate the two?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the vertical reaction force $N$ is uniformly distributed over the area, you can integrate the torque $d\tau = r\cdot \mu dN$, given $dN/N = dA/A$. The area $dA$ is easier to write in polar coordinates $dA=r\,dr\,d\phi$.

Your plan for the rest of the problem is correct. However, there is an alternative approach. From angular momentum conservation, we can find the resulting angular velocity and the total change in angular momentum $\Delta J$. And since $\tau$ doesn't depend on the speed, $T=\Delta J/\tau$